# Im trying to enable the user to only select one checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

In my code, when a checkbox is selected an image is displayed. But when i select another checkbox the first image does not disappear and another image comes out.

What i really want is if i select a checkbox the first time and an image is displayed, I want it to disappear when i select a different checkbox so that the image of that checkbox can take its place. Any insights will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="pics/35.jfif" > 
<input type="checkbox" />
<img src="pics/38.jfif" > 
</body>

<style>
img {
display: none
}

input {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
```

}

input:checked +img {
display: block
}
`

Comment: What you looking for is called radio button!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use radio instead of checkbox like:

```css
img {
  display: none
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

input:checked+img {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="radio" name="image" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <input type="radio" name="image" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
</fieldset>
```

Reference:

- [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Answer (score -1):

if you can add input id and add img class you can work. Simple version use it.

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="inpt_1"/>
    <img src="pics/35.jfif" class="img_1"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="inpt_2"/>
    <img src="pics/38.jfif" class="img_2"> 
    
    
    
        img {
          display: none;
        }
    
        #inpt_1:checked + .img_1{
          display: block;
        }
        
        #inpt_2:checked + .img_2{
          display: block;
        }
```

Comment: technical incorrect. It is not necessary to use an ID. What you have shown works fine without an ID. However, it does not answer or provide a solution to the question.  It does not answer how you could only select one checkbox and would deselect other checkboxes when you select a new one (radio button).